# Is it possible to integrate ROS2 with Nvidia Drive PX?

Tags: ros, ros2, nvidia, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

has anyone tried integrating NVIDA drive PX with ROS2 ? Some guidelines would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303173/is-it-possible-to-integrate-ros2-with-nvidia-drive-px-?/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-09-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While I don't have access to that hardware to confirm it, if you run compatible combination of Linux and ROS 2 distributions as specified in [REP-2000](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/blob/master/rep-2000.rst) it should just work.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-09-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0